# Does the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/(x^2+n^2)$ converge to a function with a continuous derivative?

Tags: calculus

I saw a solution to this question but I have a few questions regarding it. In the solution, it was proven that the original sum converges uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$. Isn't this unnecessary? Doesn't the question only call to check that the sum of $f(n) = \frac{1}{x^2+n^2} $converges point-wise and that the sum $f'(n)$ converges uniformly to some $g(x)$?

In solving the question, the solution showed how the sum of $f'(n)$ converges uniformly, which I had trouble understanding. Can anyone provide some clarity?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the $f_n$ are continuously differentiable, and $\sum_n f_n'$ converges uniformly on any bounded set to some $g$ (which must be continuous), and suppose $\sum_n f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to some function $f$.

Let $\phi(x) = \int_{x_0}^x g(t) dt$, then uniform convergence gives
$\phi(x) = \sum_n \int_{x_0}^x f_n'(t) dt = \sum_n (f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)) = f(x) -f(x_0)$. Since $g$ is continuous, it follows that $\phi$ is differentiable and
$\phi'(x) = g(x) = f'(x)$. That is, $f$ is differentiable and $f' = g$.  (It also follows that $\sum_n f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, but that's not relevant here.)

Now let $f_n(x) = {1 \over x^2+n^2}$, then  have $f_n'(x) = - {2 x \over (x^2+n^2)^2 }$. Since $|f_n(x)| \le {1 \over n^2}$, and $|f_n'(x)| \le 2 { |x| \over n^4}$, we see that $f_n(x)$ converges for all $x$ and that $\sum_n f_n'$ converges uniformly to some continuous function $g$ on any bounded set. Then the previous result shows that $\sum_n f_n$ converges to a differentiable function whose derivative is $g$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Why is it enough to show uniform convergence on bounded sets if the functions we're talking about are defined on R? Is it case specific, in that we're talking about a derivative?

Comment: In this case the convergence (of $f_n'$) is not uniform in $x$ (because of the $x$ term in the numerator). For the purposes of showing differentiability, we need only consider $x$ in some interval $(a,b)$. (Similarly to show continuity at some point, we can restrict the domain to some interval.)